# Using powerline adaptor on Multiple Networks on the same circuit

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

I need to have 2 networks on the same circuitry using powerline adapters.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  To do so, you will need two (or more) powerline devices configured with the same encryption key, and another two (or more) devices configured with a different encryption key than the first pair.

However, since they use the same medium to communicate on, this will decrease performance and may decrease signal strength between the devices.